# Run native plugins in browser with Capacitor

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native, capacitor

I’d like to see native plugins working in my browser when I’m developing, but I get the error “Native: tried calling NativeGeocoder.reverseGeocode, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator”

So Cordova might have a way to simulate that, but not Capacitor. To those who use Cordova, the general solution would be to run “ionic cordova run browser” but I get

“[ERROR] Refusing to use Cordova inside a Capacitor project”

But if I try to run “ionic capacitor run browser”, I get:

“[error] platform browser not found”

What can I do to run native plugins in web platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cordova` and `Capacitor` are different frameworks. Most of `Cordova` plugins only support mobile platforms (iOS, Android...), and you can't use them in your browser, as you pointed it out in your question with the `NativeGeocoder` plugin.

`Capacitor` main objective is to help developers create mobile applications with Ionic, which can be used as PWA. That's why `Capacitor` plugins are supported on the browser platform.
For example, [capacitorgeolocation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v3/apis/geolocation#capacitorgeolocation) works with `ionic serve`, while the [cordova-plugin-geolocation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation) does not work on the web (you will receive a message "Cordova not available").

But Capacitor does not provide yet any `NativeGeocoder` plugin, so if you want to geocode addresses on the web, your only solution is to rely on API web services (like Mapbox or Google Maps). Because the `NativeGeocoder` plugin relies on native code to work.